# How to start x64 bit application from x86 application in c#

Tags: c#, 64-bit

I have to start x64 bit application that is located under c:\windows\system32 (it is x64 bit system). I have x86 application that shout start it. I use c# Process class. What should I do in order to runt this application ? The problem is that when I point to this application through Process.Start("c:\windows\system32\app.exe") I get version from c:\windows\sysWOW64.

Comment: how downvoted this question? and why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your problem is that the 32 bit application can't see the 64 bit system32 directory.  You can use `c:\windows\sysnative` instead if you have to specify a full path.  Alternatively you should just be able to name the program without its path, i.e. `MyExecutable.exe` rather han `c:\windows\system32\MyExecutable.exe`.

Comment: When I give application name I get application from SysWow64, so x86 version.